# Appending filename information to RDD initialized by sc.textFile

Tags: apache-spark

I have a set of log files I would like to read into an RDD.
These files are all compressed .gz and are the filenames are date stamped.
The source of these files is the page view statistics data for wikipedia

http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/

The file names look like this:

```
pagecounts-20090501-000000.gz
pagecounts-20090501-010000.gz
pagecounts-20090501-020000.gz
```

What I would like to do is read in all such files in a directory and prepend the date from the filename (e.g. 20090501) to each row of the resulting RDD.
I first thought of using *sc.wholeTextFiles(..)* instead of *sc.textFile(..)*, which creates a PairRDD with the key being the file name with a path,
but *sc.wholeTextFiles()* doesn't handle compressed .gz files.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: what version of Spark are you using? wholeTextFiles seems to work fine in Spark 1.6.0

Comment: Check the code I put on my answer, I don't have 1.5.2 handy to test it here

Comment: Ok I will, thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work fine for me in `Spark 1.6.0`:

`sc.wholeTextFiles("file:///tmp/*.gz").flatMapValues(y => y.split("\n")).take(10).foreach(println)`

Sample output:

> (file:/C:/tmp/pagecounts-20160101-000000.gz,aa 271_a.C 1 4675)
>   (file:/C:/tmp/pagecounts-20160101-000000.gz,aa  Battaglia_di_Qade%C5%A1/it/Battaglia_dell%27Oronte 1 4765)
>   (file:/C:/tmp/pagecounts-20160101-000000.gz,aa Category:User_th 1
>   4770)
>   (file:/C:/tmp/pagecounts-20160101-000000.gz,aa Chiron_Elias_Krase 1 4694)

Comment: Thus seems to have done the trick. It works on Spark 1.5.2. Thanks much.

Comment: Is there anyway to use sc.textFiles on a set of files and obtain the filename for each so I can append it to the row in the RDD instead of using sc.wholeTextFiles ? I have run into Java heap memory issues due to what I think is the usage of `flatMapValues`.

Comment: There is no way to do it as far as I'm aware, you could have a look at the code to see who the two are implemented and maybe spin off your own custom logic